# How do I get the viewport in pixels in Mapbox?

Tags: mapbox, viewport, mapbox-android, mapbox-ios

How do I get the viewport of the `Camera` in pixels `Android` / `iOS`? I'm trying to use `padding` to shift the viewport but how do I get the size of viewport?

Current code, hard-coding `1300` which most likely won't work on other screen sizes this is why I need the `viewport`'s size

```java
double[] padding = {0, 1300, 0, 0};
return new CameraPosition.Builder()
    .padding(padding)
    .target(center)
    .bearing(getDirectionForUserLocationUpdate())
    .tilt(mPitch)
    .zoom(zoomLevel)
    .build();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Class MapView` has a method `getHeight()` that's how you can retrieve the height.